# extra space when replace with unicode equivalent

Tags: javascript, meteor, unicode

This Meteor server code is inserting an extra space when `console.log(x)` to the meteor terminal.
How can this be fixed? Thanks

```
let x = '1.1'
x = x.replace('.', "\uff0E");
console.log(x);
//gives 1. 1 instead of just 1.1
```

Comment: If the expected output is 1.1, then the best solution is to comment out the second line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\uff0E` is a full-width full stop [`．`]. It is not a "unicode equivalent" of a [`.`]). When I run your code, I get this:

> 1．1

Notice that this is three characters, not four. The gap after the dot is part of the glyph.

Comment: So what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: It depends on what exactly the problem is. If the problem is replacing one character with another (wrong) character, the solution is simply to stop doing the replacement. If the problem is that the character doesn't look like you want it to look, maybe use a different character. If the problem is that you think that `\uff0e` is a "unicode equivalent" for a full stop, then the solution is to stop thinking that. You can't really change unicode.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris said `\uff0E` is a full-width full stop `[．]` and not for `[.]`

You can use Unicode equivalent of `[.]` in the 2nd line, i.e.`\u002E`

```js
    let x = '1.1'
    x = x.replace('.', "\u002E");
    console.log(x);
    // would give you 1.1
```